# Update a field in mongodb collection even if it doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to set `isChecked` field to mongodb collection even if this field does not exist in the collection:

```
User.updateOne({ id }, { $set: { isChecked: true } });
```

But it doesnt update because `isChecked` does not exist. I remember it was something with `new` but I dont remember exactly.

P.S. I love mongodb but I hate it's documentation. 0 readability

Comment: For me it is working even if the field doesn't exists. `User.updateOne({ id }, { $set: { isChecked: true } })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of this query should not depend on if `isChecked` exists; the `$set` operator will set the value of `isChecked`, [regardless of if the field exists in the document before or not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior):

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
>   specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
>   constraint.

Were you possibly thinking of [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) or some other behavior with incrementing?